# floppy disk controller mobo no connector RAID XP

Tags: windows-xp, raid, floppy

I want to install a floppy disk drive, but my new ASUS P8Z68-V LX mobo does not have the floppy drive connection pins on it.  What can I do?  Is there an adapter?  Or does a USB-floppy work at XP boot-up time in order to load RAID drivers?

---

Ok, I bought the usb floppy and did the F6 thing, but it still doesn't boot up in RAID. mode! What is going on?  I can boot up this xp pro sp3 system in IDE mode no pingroblem.  I switch to RAID mode, boot up, go to Windows recovery and do the F6 t mode hing.  This seems to work ok, but it still doesn't boot in RAID mode.  What am I missing?  The raid mode boot seems to start but goes to bios then the xp recovery screens.  Thank you.

Comment: "IDE mode"? That motherboard has no IDE.

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that you will have to either use a USB floppy drive, or purchase an add-on card that supports floppy drives.

Comment: Justin is correct; not only is there [no obvious way](http://ca.asus.com/websites/Global/products/QbKg5KhI5BjopWec/6Vadu4lAZyj9x8rS_500.jpg) to connect a floppy drive (or IDE drives for that matter), but the [manual](http://ca.asus.com/en/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8Z68V_LX/#download) does not even *mention* the term *floppy* (or IDE). That board also has no serial or parallel ports *or connectors*. It is just one of those ultra-modern, future-looking boards that all abandons backward-compatibility (which some of us despise) for performance and simplicity.